# How can I open a single changeset in TFS from within Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, changeset

Someone emailed me a TFS changeset ID and now I am trying to open this single changeset.  Is there an easy was to do this from within Visual Studio (VS 2008 if it matters)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the Source Control Explorer (View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer):

1. Right click on the folder you want to grab
2. Click **Get Specific Version**
3. Change the dropdown from "Latest Version" to "**Changeset**"
4. Find your changeset on via the browse (...) button.
5. Change to search to changeset number

Just select the result and hit ok.

Alternatively, if you want to see what **changes** were in that changeset...

1. Go to the same **Source Control Explorer**
2. Click the **History** button (looks like a clock)
3. Scroll down the changeset list that appears, double click the one you want.

This will list the files changed in that changeset as well as notes the developer put.

Comment: Cool, this works even if it is less than intuitive or direct.  Thanks

Comment: Except that not all changesets are IN that history changeset list, so you might not find your changeset there.

Answer (score 69):

In Visual Studio a keyboard shortcut can be used for pulling up a specific Changeset or Work Item.

**Go to Changeset**

In Visual Studio open the *Source Control Explorer* window and while it has context press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. Enter the number in the *Go To Changeset* dialog and press OK.

[image: Go to Changeset dialog]

I know this works in VS 2010, 2012 and 2013, but recall this working as far back as at least Visual Studio 2008.

**Go to Work Item**

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> when the *Team Explorer Work Items* window has context brings up the *Go To Work Item* dialog:

[image: Go to Work Item dialog]

In Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 the *TEAM* menu contains an option *Go to Work Item* which also brings up this dialog.

**Last Word**

Visual Studio is a very contextual program and what happens when a specific keyboard command is used is oftentimes influenced by what window has context. To be clear pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> when an editor window is open will present the *Go To Line* dialog.

[image: Go to Line dialog]

As with many keyboard commands in Visual Studio your mileage will vary.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll see if I can manually make a global shortcut to do this since, in many other windows, CTRL+G takes you to "Go to TFS Work Item".

Comment: @Jaxidian: Were you able to create a shortcut for this?

Comment: Loving that tip, really handy!

Answer (score 3):

or, from a VS command prompt type "tf changeset 1234" (make sure that your root folder is inside of your workspace or you will have to explicitly define the team project etc.)

Comment: Definitely works, even if it is not completely within visual studio. I suppose that I could add an add-in to do it from with VS...or deal with being at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remember `Ctrl + G` shortcut, just do as below.

`Open the source Control Explorer -> Right Click -> Find in Source Control -> Changeset`
Then a dialog box will appear where u can specify your changeset number hit find. And it will appear in results section at the bottom, then you could go into all its details.

Answer (score 1):

In the NugGet console, you can use the TFS Powershell Snapin from the TFS PowerTools.

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell
Get-TfsChangeset <ChangesetNumber>
```

Another option is to open Tools > External Tools and add a new external tool that calls `TF.exe changeset` and prompts for arguments where you can give the changeset number.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2012 you have the option to search in changesets.

if you want to **search** changeset...

1. Go to `Source Control Explorer` Click the `Find Changeset`(looks like some papers tied together) button. it is near to history button (looks like a clock)
2. you can search by changes checkedin by a user,containing file,and date range
3. try to add as much filter as possible, otherwise it will take sometime to load.