# Visual Studio: How do I get a list of files in a project affected by a given changeset?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, version-control, changeset

Given a changeset number of Visual Studio Team Foundation System 2008, is there an easy way to find out which files in my project/solution were edited in the changeset?

Comment: same as this one, the answers are more detailed in steps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196754/how-can-i-open-a-single-changeset-in-tfs-from-within-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on a source file that's in the changeset, and select View History. The history window will open, and show you all the changesets for that file. Double-click on a changeset, and you will see the list of items changed in that changeset.

Comment: +1...or, if you don't know any of the files that were changed, you can do "View History" on the base project node in the Source Control Explorer and find your changeset there.